# ClickableText styling in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to change the style of a clickable text, mostly its font and color. Here's my code:

```
ClickableText(
    text = AnnotatedString(stringResource(R.string.forgot_password)),
    onClick = { offset ->
        Log.d("ClickableText", "$offset -th character is clicked.")
    }
)
```

This is just using the default theme. How can I apply a different color or font?

Comment: `Seb` is a Hindi word, meaning 'Apple', really.

Answer (score 6):

It offers the `style` parameter. You could just do something like

```kotlin
ClickableText(
    text = AnnotatedString(""),
    onClick = {},
    style = TextStyle(
        color = Blue,
        fontSize = 26.sp,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive
    )
)
```

If you are using Android Studio, you can just press `Ctrl + P` on Windows and `Cmd + P` on Mac to check the available parameters. The optional parameters are not inserted by code completion since they can be many.

Comment: how to apply style from material3 typography?, Say I want to style text as Typography.bodyMedium.

Comment: @VidyeshChuri Have a look at [Francesc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049924/15880865)

Answer (score 1):

To use fonts, define a `fontFamily` property, like this

```
private val Montserrat = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.montserrat_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(R.font.montserrat_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.montserrat_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
)
```

then add it to your Typography

```
val Typography = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = Montserrat,
        fontSize = 96.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        lineHeight = 117.sp,
        letterSpacing = (-1.5).sp
    ),
```

which is added to your theme

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = colors,
    typography = Typography,
    shapes = Shapes,
    content = content
)
```

If you then use these styles in your text it will pick the family you specified, or you can override, like this

```
Text(
    text = "Sample text",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
        color = Color.Blue,
        fontFamily = Montserrat,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style keyword to add font, for example:

```
ClickableText(
  text = AnnotatedString(text = "Clickable Text Font Example"),
  style = TextStyle(
    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.your_font)),
  ),
  onClick = {}
)
```